# como puedo solucionar este error en c#

Tags: c#

```
static double LeerAños()
   {
        int az;
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los años que se le daran de plazo");
        az = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while(!(az >= 2 && az <= 7))
        {
         Console.WriteLine("ERROR\n Ingrese los años que se le daran de plazo");
         az = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
      return az;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué error? No has incluido ningún detalle...

Answer (score 2):

> como puedo solucionar este error en c#

Tristemente, no nos has dicho cual es tu error. En el futuro, sería bueno incluir todos los detalles relevantes en tu pregunta.

Aun así, siendo que tu programa no es complicado, solo veo un tipo de error que te pueda dar problemas.  Esto sucedería cuando durante la entrada de datos, el valor no es numérico.  En ese caso, el uso de `int.Parse` te va a lanzar un `NumberFormatException`.

Para evitar este error, necesitas usar [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) en vez de `int.Parse`. En vez de lanzar un `NumberFormatException`, [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) te devuelve `false` si el valor no es numérico, y `true` si lo es.

Haciendo unas pequeñas mejoras en tu código:

- Reemplazando `int.Parse` por [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Cambiando el tipo de la función de `double` a `int`
- Traduciendo la condición `!(az >= 2 && az <= 7)` a `az < 2 || az > 7`
- Evitando repetición innecesaria moviendo el parse directamente dentro del `while`

... tu método quedaría así:

```
static int LeerAños()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los años que se le daran de plazo");
    int az;

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out az) || az < 2 || az > 7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR\n Ingrese los años que se le daran de plazo");
    }

    return az;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una manera mas optima de implementar, podria ser asi:

```
static int LeerAnios()
    {
        int az;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los años que se le daran de plazo");
            az = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        } while (!(az >= 2 && az <= 7));
        return az;
    }
```

Saludos, espero que te sirva.

Comment: ¿Cuál era el problema? ¿Cómo lo solucionaste con este código? Sería recomendable agregar una descripción de por qué esto responde a la pregunta y cómo